# Flexbox item height for mobile

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I am experimenting with flexbox, learning responsive layouts with media queries. However I can not work out how to retain container height when I change flex-direction: from row to column. Anyone know where I am going wrong? Thanks!

[Here is the Codepen](https://codepen.io/thinkvisual/pen/RwRpaPP)

Here is the HTML

```
<body>
  
<div class="flex-wrap">
      
  <div class="flex-container">
    
    <div class="flex-item">
      <h3>Box One</h3>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="flex-item">
      <h3>Box two</h3>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      <h3>Box three</h3>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">
        
    <div class="flex-item">
      <h3>Box two</h3>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item">
      <h3>Box three</h3>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Here is the SCSS

```
.flex-wrap {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.flex-container {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    gap: 20px;
    // flexbox stuff
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    div {
        background-color: tomato;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.flex-item {
    flex: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .flex-container {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... its got height: auto which, at the moment means it'll fit to the content. So you can just change that to height: 500px or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property is causing the issue:

```
.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Not sure why you put it there, but disabling it and it would be with the appropriate height.

Comment: Ahhhh just removed it and works perfectly. Thank you : )